# Javascript Object properties in a separate file

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I have a JavaScript object with thousands of properties and what i want if possible  is to have these properties in a separate file (lets say a txt) so that the admin of the system will be able to make changes at his will without messing with the code.

Is this possible?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfect application for [JSON](http://json.org/example.html) (Javascript Object Notation). It allows you to store name/values pairs in a tree structure that acts as a "mini database". It's lightning fast, easy to navigate, and is widely used in may platforms.

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds good. Does this mean that the admin has to deal with xml files? I was looking for something simpler like a txt with text only like this "foo":"bar". But no worries if thats the case!

Comment: JSON is a .js file. It mirrors a lot of the same features as XML, but you don't have to parse it because it can be treated as a JavaScript array in code. You can make the structure as simple or complex as you need.